# Access VBA App Fails on Azure VM

Tags: azure, ms-access, vba, virtual-machine

I have a legacy application written in MS Access VBA that I'm trying to port to an Azure Windows VM. I am running the application interactively via remote desktop.

It fails on a VBA statement that has always worked when run on a local physical machine.

The statement is:

```
        With tdf
            .connect = ";DATABASE=" & strUseDB
```

where tdf is a TableDef object and strUseDB is the filename of an access database on a local drive.

Running this on an Azure VM results in an "Invalid Operation" error 3219 being raised.

I've tried this on both Windows Server 2016 and Windows 10 VMs with the same result.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you provide some more information in the path used in strUseDB? I'm thinking this might have something to do with permissions or trust back to a location on C drive?

Comment: What is the value of `strUseDB`?

Comment: strUseDB = "C:\WEMSIM\Model\TestModel.mdb" (The quotes are not part of the string)

Comment: Can you right click on the database file and make sure it's not set to read-only or locked.